# Trigger A dialog at specific time?

Tags: android, datepicker, android-alertdialog, datetimepicker, timepicker

I dont know how to get a system day and compare it with the day user pickep up from DatePicker. Something like :

```
if (systemtime) = (timePicker) then
show dialog ("This is your birthday")
```

This is the code for user picks up date :
 private class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
            implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

```
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        if(friend == null) {
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        }

        int year = friend.getYear();
        int month = friend.getMonth();
        int day = friend.getDayOfMonth();

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        birthday.set(year, month, day);
    }
```

Comment: Please learn how to code instead of copy/paste.

Answer (score 1):

try below approach:

set a alarm in alarm manager and fire a pending intent on alarm time. through pending intent you can start a activity as new task, now you can set theme of activity as Dialog. in alarm you can specify specific time for open dialog activity.

Answer (score 0):

I think you take wrong path to set dialog at specific dialog.you have to take pending intent and set your friend birthday time and that's it when time complete dialog automatically generated.
You don't want to create service for that and compare day by day.i hope you understand...

Comment: thks for reply. There will be a button "Check Birthday" which compares value from datePicker and system day to show a dialog. I am confusing how to make it done.

Comment: ok then just get current date and your stored friend birthday date and compare but first check both date format are same.

Comment: Can I store both of them as string format to compare?

Comment: Can I use this method to compare ?

Comment: down vote
 

protected boolean checkDateValidity(Date date){
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(date.getYear() + 1900, date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), date.getHours(), date.getMinutes());
        if((cal.getTimeInMillis()-System.currentTimeMillis()) <= 0){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }

Comment: nop my friend this cant work because GregorianCalendar starting year is 1900 and our system clock starting year is 1970 so you doesnot get right value.

Comment: change 1900 to 1970 and check it... and why are you convert both date in milliseconds and then check? just store both date in string and compare thats it..